# Flutter Stack ListView over Footer

Tags: flutter, layout, stack, footer, positioning

I want to create a website where the footer sticks to the bottom of the page but the items of a ListView which fills out the whole page overlap the footer until the user scrolls all the way up.

**For example:** The footer has a height of 350 and the last element of the listview is a container with a height of 350. The problem is that the items in the footer are not clickable if it is underneath the list of items. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is a sample of my setup so far:

```dart
...,
children: [
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: FooterWidget(),      //Container of height 350 with some TextButtons, etc.
            ),
            ListView(..., Container(height: 350,),)

children: [
  Positioned(
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    child: FooterWidget(), // Container of height 350 with some TextButtons, etc.
  ),
  ListView(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 350,
        ...
      ),
      ...
    ],
  ),
]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried using `Column` instead of `Stack`? The children of `Column` would be `Expanded(child: ListView(...))` for the first child and `SizedBox(height: 350, child: FooterWidget())` for the last.

Comment: @WillHlas This would not achieve the logic I want because the footer would be seen all the time. What I want to achieve is that the footer is revealed only at the end of the ListView.